# Sudden high latency spikes in same subnet

Tags: networking

I have 2 vms under VMWare ESXI which are built from the same template (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS OS). However one is copied manually from a template using the vSphere UI (172.16.1.207 ser-notf-01) and the other one is made by Terraform using the vSphere api (172.16.1.209 terraformtest) which creates a vm from the same template. They are in the same VLAN, same subnet and the traffic goes only through the host OS network interface so there are no physical routers/switches involved here. What I have been noticing, when I ping them from a third example server (172.16.1.222 ser-staging-01) which is stable and has been running for a while I get spikes when pinging "terraformtest" but not when I ping "ser-notf-01".

```
root@ser-staging-01:-# ping 172.16.1.207 
PING 172.16.1.207 (172.16.1.207) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.334 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.325 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.407 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.292 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.329 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.295 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.259 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.207: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.310 ms
C
--- 172.16.1.207 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12265ms ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.259/0.318/0.407/0.042
root@ser-staging-01:~# ping 172.16.1.209
PING 172.16.1.209 (172.16.1.209) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.833 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.373 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=7.21 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=55.8 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.484 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.438 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.805 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=26.2 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.473 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp seq=12 ttl=64 time=5.29 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.517 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.1.209: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.470 ms
```

so to recap, same subnet, same VMX file and hypervisor configurations, same physical server and no routing involved and both made from the same template, I've tried this over 5-6 times with different templates and the only pattern seems to be the involvement of "Terraform" which doesn't make sense to me either.
Things I've tried:

- Duplicated IP
- Duplicated MAC
- OS arp cache to make sure the right MAC is set for the corresponding IP
- Sysctl configurations
- Different tools and protocols to make sure it's not just an icmp issue
- Changing IP address and MAC address on the mentioned server
- Quadruple checked to see if the vm parameters were the same for both vms

What I'm hoping to achieve here is to either find a fix to this issue or know the concepts or the tools to search for to be able to troubleshoot the issue.
This issue partially relates to the OS, I know that some people might see otherwise and in that case I would be happy to know the correct places to ask this question.

Comment: Do you see the latencies also when pinging between the VMs? Do you see them when pinging the external machine from either of the VMs? If the answer to all of these is no, then I'd conclude the issue is in the host's networking setup (or something else between the `.209` and the external server - e.g. another machine with that IP?), and there is little to do on the Ubuntu machines.

Comment: If you do think the issue is in the VMs, it will be helpful to add the output of `ip route` from each of them to your question.

Comment: @zwets
When I ping other machines from either vm the same applies, the one with network issues sometimes gets higher latencies, but the spikes are much much smaller. if 2 machines which have these symptoms ping one another then the spikes become much more noticeable as well.

Comment: I'm quite sure this has nothing to do with my routing table (considering how everything is happening in the same subnet) but:

default via 172.16.1.254 dev ens160 proto static

172.16.1.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.209

default via 172.16.1.254 dev ens160 proto static

172.16.1.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.207

Comment: You mention _"2 machines which have these problems"_, meaning it happens _every time_ you build a server with Terraform? Clearly then the issue is with Terraform. What is your reason to not tackle it from that end? It'll be needle-in-a-haystack to diagnose this from within the Ubuntu VM. Of course, you could go through the `sudo lshw` from both machines to spot hardware differences, but I'd expect it much easier to glean that from the Terraform logs. And either way, that's also where the issue will need to be fixed.